# "Cannot run console until path to viable R interpeter is specified" in Intellij

Tags: r, intellij-idea

The `R` interpreter is defined in the `Settings | R Settings` :

[image]

But I am unable to run a simple `R` command/script via

```
install.packages("benford.analysis")
```

[image]

Why is the interpreter not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had installed the `R` plugin and did *not* restart the IDE. In the past *Intellij-Idea* had always required a restart. I had thought - given I was *not* required to restart before using the plugin - that maybe in the lastest 2021.2.X they had relaxed that requirement.

Well what happened is the plugin *partially* worked : syntax highlighting popped up and the R commands / menu items appeared.  But apparently this "install plugins without restart" is not reliable - at least for the `R` plugin.  After restarting IJ the problem desribed inthe question disappeared and *R* scripts appear  to be working within Intellij now.